# Value of 'spark.executor.instances' shown in 'Environment' page

Tags: apache-spark

In our Application ,We have submitted Spark job with the following configuration values:
'--num-executors' (or) 'spark.executor.instances' - Not set 
'spark.executor.cores' -  Not set 
'spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled' -'True'   
'spark.executor.memory' - 1g 
(No.of worker nodes available - 3 having 4 vCores each)

In 'Environment' page of Spark Web UI, following values are observed : 
'spark.executor.instances' - '3' 
'spark.executor.cores' - '4'

**Can we assume that the above values  shown for 'spark.executor.instances' (3) and
'spark.executor.cores' (4) are the initial values only  ?**

The reason for this assumption is ,
From the 'Executors' page it can be observed that total '14' executors are used.

From the 'Event Timeline' , it can be observed that at one moment, maximum '8' executors' are running .Since total number of cores available are '12' (3 x 4) only , it looks like the number of cores used per executor also will not be constant during runtime. i.e. Initially it starts with '4' but will reduce when the number of executors increase!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You post cover 2 questions:

1. Are the initial value of `spark.executor.instances` and `spark.executor.cores` `3` and `4` respectively? It depends on which mode are you using. Based on the configurations that you provide, which you set the `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` be `True`, and you mentioned that you have `3` nodes with `4` cores each, it will scales your number of executors based on workload. Also, If you're running your spark application on YARN, the default value of `spark.executor.cores` should be `1`. As you didn't mention about your mode and number of spark application that you run at the same time, I assume you're only running a single spark job and you're not running in YARN mode. You can check the spark config based on the option you input: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html
2. Will the number of `cores` and `executors` differ from what you config your in `spark-submit` if your number of executors increase? No, once you submitted your spark application and create the sparkContext, the number of executors and cores will not change, unless you create the new one.

Comment: The Spark job is running in 'Yarn' mode on EMR-5.29.0 and only one Spark application is being executed.                                                                                                               
If the number of cores doesn't change , then when 8 executors are running , total number of cores in use should be 8*4 = 32 . But only 12 are available. How is it possible ?

Comment: @tryData Could you capture the information `maximum '8' executors' are running` on Event Timeline that you mentioned? Are you talking about the event timeline when you click into the stage? I believe you are mixing up the `task`, `executor` and `core` in the Web UI.

Comment: Please find the snapshots attached above

Comment: Hi @tryData, I have two questions: 1. what is the resources (no. of core and memory size) and number of instances in EMR-5.29.0? 2. What's the difference if you submit the spark application with `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=False`?

Comment: Hi @Jonathan              Hardware used :
m5.xlarge instances  - Master node - 1 , Core nodes - 3.
Each - 4 vCore , 16 GiB memory.

Didn't really tried 'spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=False'